# Perform http health check on backend servers with haproxy

Tags: haproxy, gateway

Is it possible to perform HTTP healthcheck on individual backend servers and load balance among active backend servers.
This works fine with single backend server when we mention host name in httpchk (option httpchk GET  /info HTTP/1.1 Host:\ abc.mysrv1.com)

However i am unable to successfully configure it with multiple backend servers as i can't give individual host name on httpchk command and with below backend configuration getting http 400 error -

---

```
backend svc.op
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    http-send-name-header Host
    option httpchk GET  /info HTTP/1.1
    http-check send-state
    http-request set-uri /test/abcService
    server abc.mysrv1.com abc.mysrv1.com:80 check
    server abc.mysrv2.com  abc.mysrv2.com:80 check
```

---

```
[WARNING] 115/162226 (4788) : Server svc.op/abc.mysrv1.com is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 400, info: "Bad Request: missing required Host header", check duration: 1ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 115/162227 (4788) : Server svc.op/abc.mysrv2.com is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 400, info: "Bad Request: missing required Host header", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 115/162227 (4788) : backend ' svc.op' has no server available!
```

$ ./haproxy -version
HA-Proxy version 1.6.7 2016/07/13

UPDATE:
I didn't pursue this but someone suggested following  -

```
backend h_a01
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /health HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ a01\r\n
    http-check expect rstatus ^200
    http-request set-uri /hello/world
    http-request set-header Host a01
    server a01 a01 check

backend h_a02
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /health HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ a02\r\n
    http-check expect rstatus ^200
    http-request set-uri /hello/world
    http-request set-header Host a02
    server a02 a02 check

backend a
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    http-send-name-header Host
    http-request set-uri /hello/world
    server a1 a1 track h_a01/a01
    server a2 a2 track h_a02/a02
```

Comment: Have you ever managed to get this working? I am sitting with the same issue.

Comment: see my update above, share if this works.